# Spring: unable to use property placeholders in Unit Testing

Tags: java, spring, junit, properties

i'm developing an spring 4.0 REST application and it works fine, but when i try to make some test it fails at reading propety values from placeholders (they work fine if i run the app normally)

Some of the properties of the app come from files and other from database so i have configured an PropertiesPropertySource to read them from db. I was unable to config it by xml, so i did it in a @Configuration class:

```
public class AppConfig {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AppConfig.class);

    @Inject
    private org.springframework.core.env.Environment env;

    @Autowired  
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initializeDatabasePropertySourceUsage() {
        MutablePropertySources propertySources = ((ConfigurableEnvironment) env).getPropertySources();
        try {                
            DatabaseConfiguration databaseConfiguration = new DatabaseConfiguration(dataSource, "[TABLE]", "property", "value");
            CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean commonsConfigurationFactoryBean = new CommonsConfigurationFactoryBean(databaseConfiguration);
            Properties dbProps = (Properties) commonsConfigurationFactoryBean.getObject();
            PropertiesPropertySource dbPropertySource = new PropertiesPropertySource("dbPropertySource", dbProps);           
            propertySources.addFirst(dbPropertySource);        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error during database properties setup:"+e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

}
```

In the test class i load the context config with this annotation:
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {TestConfig1.class,AppConfig.class,TestConfig2.class})

As i'm mixing XML and java configurations i had to create the TestConfigX classes which load the XMLs with this annotation:
@ImportResource([PATH TO config xml])

- TestConfig1 has the DatasourceBean definition and it works fine
- AppConfig config the PropertiesPropertySource to read the placeholders from DB
- TestConfig2 config the rest of the app, which uses the placeholders ( @Value=${XXXX}), but is unable to read the values: Could not resolve placeholder XXXX

If i omit TestConfig2 i can use the placeholders from DB in the test without problem. But obviously i´m not testing anything.

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should use an `ApplicationContextInitializer` to add a `PropertySource` to the `Environment` your current setup is too late.

Comment: Hi, i'm triying to do as you suggest, but the database PropertiesSource relies on a DataSource provided for the root-context, As the ApplicationContextInitializer is inviked before the root-context the Datasource is null and it fails

Comment: Correct you will have to create/obtain it manually and not rely on the context for that.

Comment: Thx, i did as you suggest. Its not very clean to instantiate the datasource manually, but at least it works